# "Happen to know" vs. "came to know" vs. "got to know" vs. "came across"

Tags: differences, verbs, american-english

Can anyone give use cases and examples for

- *Happen to know*
- *Came to know*
- *Got to know*
- *Came across*

I always gets confused in their uses.

Comment: Why the "American English" tag? British/Canadian/Australian English etc. have the same phrasal verbs and expressions too. Could you provide a few sentences using those expressions and explain what confuses you?

Answer (score 13):

> *Happen to know* means something like *You might not expect me to know, but I do*. It often implies that I have privy knowledge: somebody's told me a secret, or I know about something before it is published. It is quite often a boast "Look at me, I'm special, I know this information which most people don't know", but not always.
>
> *Come to know* (past: *came to know*) is a somewhat literary way of saying *find out* or *learn (a fact)*, or *become acquainted with (a person)*.
>
> *Get to know* (past: *got to know*) means *become acquainted or better acquainted with (a person)*. It is also a rather colloquial alternative to *come to know (a fact)*.
>
> *Come across* (past: *came across*) means *find by chance* or *find out by chance*.

Comment: Yes, I agree with all those. Another, rather better way of saying that you 'came to know a fact', would be to say something like: 'It came to my notice (or 'it was brought to my notice') that he had a criminal record'

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it helps but I have included a few sentences of correct usage of the expressions you mention.

'I happen to know the person you can see in that car.';
 'I came to know him when we were near-neighbours twenty years ago'. (This is less usual)
 'I got to know him and his family quite well'.
 'I recently came across his name when searching through some old paperwork'.